# What the best way to highlight a button in iOS App that collects user focus?

Tags: ios, mobile-application, user-centered-design

I am developing a mobile iOS App.

In my app, there is (what I consider) the most important section where user will able to see content related to celebrities after making in app purchase. On the home screen, there will be a button which will take the user to that screen.

What is the best attractive way to make that button highlighted? I think the most important thing in this case is to make that button looking different on the screen rather than looking beautiful. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: The word you're looking to use is what is called the 'CTA', or call to action. This is the button you want the user to use to proceed with using the application. Start by looking at classic cta examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach I could think of to make the button stand out is after the in-app purchase, once the page redirects back to this home page have the button do a quick bounce effect as if it were just placed there and have the button be a color that contrasts its surrounds and other buttons, but not wildly different like a bright red. Just use the secondary or maybe tertiary color used in the app. The movement of the animation will draw the users attention and the color will make it stand out. Be careful not to loop the animation or make it stand out too much, the user may not agree that this section is the most important and be annoyed if its too aggressive.

Bounce button idea (hover to bounce):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbVdMo